# How to handle several marshalling profiles in RestEasy?

Tags: web-services, rest, jaxb, marshalling, resteasy

I developed a RestFul web services application with RestEasy currently working on Resteasy 2.3.5 and JBoss 4.3.2GA.
I would like to publish chosen attributes to chosen users of my web services.

For instance here is an object User :
User:{id=123, name=Jack, password=MyNameIsJack}

When a web service user with an **lambda** profile ask for the object Jack my application should return :
{id=123, name=Jack}

When a web service user with an **admin** profile ask for the object Jack my application should return :
{id=123, name=Jack, **password=MyNameIsJack**}

Is there a way to do that using RestEasy Framework?

Thx

Comment: We have a feature called Object Graphs in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) that you may be able to integrate with RestEASY to get the desired behaviour:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html

Comment: Hi Blaise, this seems an acceptable solution.
However, I don't really understand how EclipseLink should integrate with RestEasy lib.
Some classes like JAXBContext are duplicated.
When I try to retrieve the JAXBContext and then use it with the JAXBHelper from EclipseLink I get the following Exception :
`code`The provided JAXBContext [class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl] is not an EclipseLink JAXBContext, and therefore could not be converted`code`
How should I use it then?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I found another way to do this using MOXy. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solution given by @Blaise Doughan but ObjectGraph override the existing annotation based mapping on my class.

What I wanted is to extend this mapping.

So I chose to do this by extending my annotation mapping with an xml mapping.
According to the tutorial by Blaise, you can do this using MOXy :
[extending-jaxb-representing-annotations](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html)

Dont forget to write a jaxb.properties file which specify which implementation of JAXB to use : [specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your-JAXB-implementation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

It's working fine for me.
Thx Blaise !